# Aligning Button in React Native

Tags: react-native

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, Image, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class ListItems extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render() {
    return (
        <FlatList
            data={this.props.text}
            renderItem={(info) => (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>   this.props.selected(info.item.key)}>
                    <View style={styles.listitems}>
                        <Image resizeMode="contain" source={info.item.image} style={styles.image} />
                        <Text>{info.item.value}</Text>
                        <View style={styles.button}>
                        <Button title="Confirm" color="blue" onPress={this.props.itemDelete}></Button>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
        >
        </FlatList>
        );
     }
 }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
listitems: {
    width: "100%",
    flex:1,
    marginTop: 5,
    backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
    padding: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
},
image: {
    marginRight: 8,
    height: 30,
    alignItems: "center",
    width: 40,
},
button: {
    width: "40%",
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
}
 })
```

I am showing list Items in which i have small image on the left then a text and i want my button to appear on extreme right but by using alignItems: 'flex-end' its showing in the center. what should i do..i want to do it without using positon.[image: I have added image of output]

Answer (score 0):

That's better I think.

```
    renderItem={(info) => (
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.itemWrapper} onPress={() =>   this.props.selected(info.item.key)}>
                    <View style={styles.itemImageContainer}>
                        <Image resizeMode="contain" source={info.item.image} style={styles.image} />
                        <Text>{info.item.value}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.button}>
                        <Button title="Confirm" color="blue" onPress={this.props.itemDelete}></Button>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
itemWrapper: {
    flex:1,
    height: 70,
    marginTop: 5,
    backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
    padding: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
},
itemImageContainer: {
    flex: 2,
    alignItems: 'center',
},
image: {
    marginRight: 8,
    height: 30,
    width: 40,
},
buttonContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
}
 })
```

Comment: it didnt work everything comes in the center in 3 rows(image,text and button).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `flex-end`, `flex-start`, `center` to align items horizantly.
you must add `flex direction :'row'` in parent component

```
buttonContainer: {
justifyContent: 'flex-end',}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add justifyContent:'space-between',alignItems:'center' to styles.listitems
This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, Image, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class ListItems extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render() {
    return (
        <FlatList
            data={this.props.text}
            renderItem={(info) => (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>   this.props.selected(info.item.key)}>
                    <View style={styles.listitems}>
                      <View>
                        <Image resizeMode="contain" source={info.item.image} style={styles.image} />
                        <Text>{info.item.value}</Text>
                       <View>
                        <View style={styles.button}>
                        <Button title="Confirm" color="blue" onPress={this.props.itemDelete}></Button>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
        >
        </FlatList>
        );
     }
 }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
listitems: {
    width: "100%",
    flex:1,
    marginTop: 5,
    backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
    padding: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent:'space-between`enter code here`'
},
image: {
    marginRight: 8,
    height: 30,
    alignItems: "center",
    width: 40,
},
button: {
    width: "40%",
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
}
 })
```